# how to get imagemagick and sqlite pdo on mac

Tags: sqlite, configuration, pdo, apache2, imagemagick

I'm trying to get both imagemagick and pdo (with sqlite) going on my imac.  I've played with the built-in apache2, ampps apache, and most recently mac ports.  Mac ports was meant to make it easy to install extensions, and I installed imagemagick ok, but then noticed that pdo had no drivers (including sqlite).  Attempts to improve on that (installing sqlite.so driver, recompiling have come to naught).  My question is: do you have both imagemagick and sqlite pdo going on your mac, and if so, how did you do it?

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me:

```
sudo port install php5-sqlite
sudo port install php5 +apache2 +sqlite
```

The second line here didn't seem to do anything, but you never know.

After restarting I noticed I didn't have imagemagick, which I thought I already had, so

```
sudo port install php5-imagick
```

Now restarting apache2 the "macports" way:

```
sudo port unload apache2
sudo port load apache2
```

And looking at phpinfo, I have sqlite2 and sqlite (which, confusingly, is sqlite3) drivers enabled for pdo.